# HTML5 radiobuttons, checkbox and select option tags: checked='checked' and selected='selected', or just checked and selected

Tags: html, tags, attributes, selected, checked

Assuming HTML5, what is the **correct** way to indicate a checkbox, radiobutton, or select option is checked or selected?

Is it like this, which appears to be commonly used but seems strangely redundant to me:

```html
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'> I'm checked

<input type='radio' checked='checked'> I'm also checked

<select>
  <option>First</option>
  <option selected='selected'>I'm selected</option>
</select>
```

Or like this, which seem to make more sense and also appears to work:

```html
<input type='checkbox' checked> I'm checked

<input type='radio' checked> I'm also checked

<select>
  <option>First</option>
  <option selected>I'm selected</option>
</select>
```

Are there any compatibility issues with the latter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `checked` or `selected` on their own.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Both ways seem to pass the [W3 HTML5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/), so they should both be correct.
I prefer the second approach as it uses less code and is easier to me, but that's completely personal.